# Can't perform a React State update on unMounted child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-state-management

Am getting this warning:

> Can't perform a React state update on unmounted component. This is a no-op...

It results from a `child component` and I can't figure out how to make it go away.

Please note that I have read many other posts about why this happens, and understand the basic issue. However, most solutions suggest cancelling subscriptions in a `componentWillUnmount` style function (I'm using `react hooks`)

I don't know if this points to some larger fundamental misunderstanding I have of React,
but here is essentially what i have:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Picker from 'emoji-picker-react';

const MyTextarea = (props) => {

  const onClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
    //do stuff...
  }

  const isMountedRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMountedRef.current = true;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log('will unmount');
      isMountedRef.current = false;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
      { isMountedRef.current ? (
          <Picker onEmojiClick={onClick}/>
        ):null
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyTextarea;
```

**(tl;dr) Please note:**

- `MyTextarea` component has a *parent* component which is only rendered on a certain route.
- Theres also a `Menu` component that once clicked, changes the `route` and *depending on the situation* will either show `MyTextarea`'s *parent* component or show another component.
- This warning happens once I click the `Menu` to switch off `MyTextarea`'s *parent* component.

**More Context**

- Other answers on *StackOverflow* suggest making changes to prevent `state` updates when a component isn't mounted. In my situation, I cannot do that because I didn't design the `Picker` component (rendered by `MyTextarea`). **The Warning originates** from this `<Picker onEmojiClick={onClick}>` line but I wouldn't want to modify this off-the-shelf component.
- That's explains my attempt to either render the component or not based on the `isMountedRef`. However this doesn't work either.  What happens is the component is either rendered if i set `useRef(true)`, or it's never rendered at all if i set `useRef(null)` as many have suggested.

Comment: This seems to be a result of `conditional rendering`. It might helpful to add the situation/condition that checks if/not to render `MyTextarea's` parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem actually is (is it that you can't get rid of the warning or that the `<Picker>` is either always rendering or never is), but I'll try to address all the problems I see.

Firstly, you shouldn't need to conditionally render the `<Picker>` depending on whether `MyTextArea` is mounted or not. Since components only render after mounting, the `<Picker>` will never render if the component it's in hasn't mounted.

That being said, if you still want to keep track of when the component is mounted, I'd suggest not using hooks, and using `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` with `setState()` instead. Not only will this make it easier to understand your component's lifecycle, but there are also some problems with the way you're using hooks.

Right now, your `useRef(true)` will set `isMountedRef.current` to `true` when the component is initialized, so it will be true even before its mounted. `useRef()` is not the same as `componentDidMount()`.

Using 'useEffect()' to switch `isMountedRef.current` to true when the component is mounted won't work either.  While it will fire when the component is mounted, `useEffect()` is for side effects, not state updates, so it doesn't trigger a re-render, which is why the component never renders when you set `useRef(null)`.

Also, your `useEffect()` hook will fire every time your component updates, not just when it mounts, and your clean up function (the function being returned) will also fire on every update, not just when it unmounts. So on every update, `isMountedRef.current` will switch from true to false and back to true. However, none of this matters because the component won't re-render anyways (as explained above).

If you really do need to use `useEffect()` then you should combine it into one function and use it to update state so that it triggers a re-render:

```
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);  // Create state variables

useEffect(() => {
  setIsMounted(true);  // The effect and clean up are in one function
  return () => {
    console.log('will unmount');
    setIsMounted(false);
  }
}, [] // This prevents firing on every update, w/o it you'll get an infinite loop
);
```

Lastly, from the code you shared, your component couldn't be causing the warning because there are no state updates anywhere in your code. You should check the picker's repo for issues.

Edit: Seems the warning is caused by your Picker package and there's already an issue for it https://github.com/ealush/emoji-picker-react/issues/142

Comment: The problem is the warning itself,  everything actually works.  as for the lifecycle functions i read that you can do them all with functional components but this doesn't seem to be true.  Also, I didn't notice the issue in the picker repo but the conversation there gives me a good idea how to fix it.  i should probably only have one of these on the screen at any time and just hide it when not used.  i'll update tomorrow on my success.    thanks.

Comment: Technically, you can use hooks for every common lifecycle function (so not `shouldComponentUpdate()`, `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`, etc.) but IMO its much trickier and less intuitive. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: Problem solved, i moved the picker up in the component tree so that there is only ever one picker and i simply display it or not when needed (and move it to the correct location on the screen).